# Can I toggle formatoptions?

Tags: vimrc

When editing email, I have "hard wrap" enabled most of the time. However, I sometimes want to turn it off (or back on), which I do with the following commands in `~/.vimrc`.

```
" turn off
command HardWrapOff :set formatoptions-=t
" turn on
command HardWrapOn :set formatoptions+=t
```

Is there a way to use a single command to toggle it depending on the current state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no builtin way of doing this that I'm aware of, but you could use a conditional like so:

```vim
command HardWrapToggle if &fo =~ 't' | set fo-=t | else | set fo+=t | endif
```